# How to install php-imap

Tags: php, imap

I need to install php-imap on my remote server.For that I have searched php -imap using below command before installing.

```
yum search php
```

Here is my result.But I coulndt find php-imap on this.How should I install php-imap on my server?

```
===================================================================== Name & Summary Matched: php ======================================================================
php.x86_64 : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath library
php-cli.x86_64 : Command-line interface for PHP
php-common.x86_64 : Common files for PHP
php-dba.x86_64 : A database abstraction layer module for PHP applications
php-dbg.x86_64 : The interactive PHP debugger
php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php-embedded.x86_64 : PHP library for embedding in applications
php-enchant.x86_64 : Enchant spelling extension for PHP applications
php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php-gd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the gd graphics library
php-gmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the GNU MP library
php-intl.x86_64 : Internationalization extension for PHP applications
php-json.x86_64 : JavaScript Object Notation extension for PHP
php-ldap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use LDAP
php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
php-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php-odbc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use ODBC databases
php-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications
php-pear.noarch : PHP Extension and Application Repository framework
php-pgsql.x86_64 : A PostgreSQL database module for PHP
php-process.x86_64 : Modules for PHP script using system process interfaces
php-recode.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the recode library
php-snmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that query SNMP-managed devices
php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
========================================================================== Name Matched: php ===========================================================================
php-opcache.x86_64 : The Zend OPcache
php-pecl-apcu.x86_64 : APC User Cache
php-pecl-apcu-devel.x86_64 : APCu developer files (header)
php-pecl-zip.x86_64 : A ZIP archive management extension
```

Comment: Can i know php version and OS version?

Comment: @MaiTruong  phpversion is PHP 7.2.24 (cli),  OS version is NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux",VERSION="8.3 (Ootpa)"

Comment: You can try 

sudo yum install php7.2-imap

Comment: No match for argument: php7.2-imap
Error: Unable to find a match: php7.2-imap
It gives this error. @MaiTruong

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the [User Contributed Notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imap.setup.php#125665) on the PHP web site. The comment was posted about ten months ago.

> For CentOS
>
> If you are using PHP 7.2, run this:
>
> yum install sclo-php72-php-imap
>
> Then restart Apache with this:
>
> systemctl restart httpd

I no longer run Red Hat Linux so I can't test it.

Comment: Didnt work for me.I tried this one too already.No match for argument: sclo-php72-php-imap